# ¿Cuál es la diferencia entre «afrecho» y «salvado»?

Tags: selección-de-palabras, vocabulario, significado

Estoy buscando la diferencia entre *afrecho* y *salvado*, como nombre para el producto de la molienda de los granos. ¿Uno de los términos es más específico que el otro?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Parece que en un principio la diferencia era meramente regional. Covarrubias dice en su diccionario (1611) lo siguiente:

> Dice Antonio Nebrija que son los salvados.

Es decir, que en 1495 ya eran voces equivalentes, pero el *Diccionario de Autoridades* (1726) nos aclara un poco la cosa:

> Lo mismo que Salvado. Es voz antigua, que yá solo tiene uso en los Réinos de Andalucía.

Esta diferencia regional también aparece en posteriores versiones del diccionario, aunque con el tiempo desapareció.

Answer (score 1):

En la definición de *afrecho*, el DLE remite directamente a *salvado*:

> [**afrecho**](http://dle.rae.es/?id=10ohnDL)
>
> Del lat. *affractum* 'quebrantado'.
>   1. m. **salvado**.

por lo que se entiende que no hay diferencia en su significado.

Aunque no aparece en el diccionario, creo que en agroindustria se habla también de *afrechillo.* Se diferencia del *afrecho* en el grado de molturación, y como sugiere el sufijo *-illo,* el *afrechillo* es más fino que el salvado.